# Incorrect proof for $\lim_{n \to \infty} c^n = 0$ where $|c|<1$, but not sure why?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Is this short proof valid for $\lim_{n \to \infty} c^n = 0$ where $|c|<1$?

*Proof*:
Limits are unique, and therefore it is sufficient to find the limit for one value of c.  Notice if $c=0$ then $c^n=0$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z_+}$.  Then given an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$, $|a_n-l|<\varepsilon ,\,\,\forall n\in\mathbb{Z_+}$.  Since the limit of a sequence is unique then $\lim_{n \to \infty} c^n = 0$.

I know it is not valid obviously because then if the condition were $\forall c$ instead of $|c|<1$ then it wouldn't make the correct result.But where am I wrong?

Comment: The sum of two numbers is also unique. Thus we conclude that $a+b=7$ for all $a,b>0$ because it is true in the special case when $a=2$ and $b=5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement is indeed true:

> If a limit of a sequence **exists**, it is unique.

In your proof you have assumed that the limit exists, but you have yet to show that it does. We don't know anything about the sequence $c^n$ until we prove it.

But even if you know that the limit exists, your proof is still wrong. The reason is that $c^n$ does not give the same sequence for every value of $c$. For example $c=0$ gives the sequence $(0)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $c=1/2$ gives the sequence $((1/2)^n)_{n=1}^\infty$. These two sequences are different.

Comment: Right, so you really can't say anything about uniqueness until you show what the limit is?

Comment: @guimption Not necessarily. Sometimes you can show that a sequence converges without knowing what the limit is. For example: If you know that a sequence is monotone and bounded, it is convergent (its limit exists).

Comment: @guimption: limit is unique for a specific sequence. Two different sequences may have different limits. Here for each $c$ the sequence $c^n$ is different.

Comment: Another example of that is a Cauchy sequence:  We know it converges, so we know the limit exists and is unique, but we don’t know what it is (and don’t need to in order to say the limit is unique).  I see, so more precisely, for a particular sequence, i.e. it is only a function of “n”, if the limit exists, then it is unique.

Comment: @guimption That is exactly right!